# Redirection error 301 and 302 with requesting web api using Alamofire

Tags: php, ios, .htaccess, redirect, alamofire

recently I've purchased `SSL` and I've redirect all the request on my server from `http` to `https` using `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

However, my `iOS` and `Android` app is is already requesting the services from `http` from `Alamofire` networking library, so its showing the following error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved 
        <a href="https://api.example.com/webservices/v1/services.php">here</a>.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know 301 and 302 are redirection error, but the webservices showing correct data from browser. Request from application not working.

Any solution to receive the correct JSON data even if redirection happen.

Please suggest what to do. Any help is appreciated.

PS: There are other reasons I can not change request in application.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

This add the `301` redirect to the `.htaccess`.

So, the complete code will be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```